# Magento2 reset button in Grid column not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I am using the UIComponent for showing the grid in front end under the customer account for a custom link.All things are going well but 'reset' button is not working in 'column' drop down for reset the visibility of columns in the grid.

Did anyone face the same issue?

Looking forward to hearing from Magento developer.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. And I found the solution.

Define bookmarks in your grid, then it will work.

Try the below code.

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
   ...
   <bookmark name="bookmarks">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customer_listing</item>
               </item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </bookmark>
   ...
</listingToolbar>
```

Hope this will work :)